# Arrange div elements horizontally and make the background scroll

Tags: html, css

I am using `column-count:2` to add elements in a div vertically and hence arrange them horizontally. I have given the div a gradient background. I want it to move with the scroll (the background). The code I am using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.prodLarge {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

#dispTiles {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  right:10px;
  margin:10px;
  overflow:auto;
  -moz-column-count:2;
  -webkit-column-count:2;
  column-count:2;
  padding:10px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to left, #141414 0%, #323232 50%, #000000 100%);
  background-attachment:scroll;
}
</style>
<div id="pagecont">
    <div id="dispTiles">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
    </div>
</div>
```

The `background-attachment:scroll` doesn't seem to be working as I want. Can anyone please assist? Also, will the solution work even if I use a background PNG image with repeat-x? And is there any better way to arrange div elements horizontally than setting `column:2`?

Answer (score 0):

To make the horizontal scrolling effect, I would do something like:

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ySHcL/

**Based off your original CSS**

```
.prodLarge {
  margin-bottom:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#dispTilesWrapper {
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  bottom:10px;
  right:50px;
  margin:10px;
  overflow:auto;
}
#dispTiles {
  height: 250px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding:10px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to left, #000000 0%, #141414 10%, #555555 20%, #000000 25%);
  /* background: url('some_path_to_an_image') repeat-x; */
  display:table;
}
```

**HTML with wrapper element**

```
<div id="pagecont">
    <div id="dispTilesWrapper">
      <div id="dispTiles">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
        <img class="prodLarge" src="http://microsoft.com/favicon.ico">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I added a wrapper around #dispTiles so that you can get the background element to scroll correctly. By the way, `background-attachment: scroll` is default behavior, so you don't need to specify it. You typically only observe it's effect during vertical scrolling, though. To get the background to span the width of the content, you'll want to add `display: table;` otherwise, the background will only repeat through the width of the viewport and not the width of the content. Instead of using `column-count`, I simply use the `white-space` property set to `nowrap`. Images tend to display inline, but they wrap by default...so, this will make them not wrap and give you the behavior you want.

Hope this helps.